# Change label of flexform select item in TYPO3 extension tx_news

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I want to add a new sorting option to the flexform in the frontend plugin of the TYPO3 extension tx_news. This works fine so far with these additions:

**ext_tables.php** of my theme extension:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['news']['orderByNews'] .= ',archive';
```

**TypoScript configuration** within my theme extension:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.orderByAllowed := addToList(archive)
```

What I miss now is the possibility to change the label of the new item `archive` in the select field `Sort by` of the flexform.

I assume it is done via page TSconfig and `TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.news_pi1.sDEF.settings.orderBy` but I can't figure out exactly how.

TYPO3 version is 6.2

Comment: I don't know how the extension is building the select. But normally you should be able to use `altLabels` as mentioned at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html

There you can use any language file you want. Even inside of your theme extension.

Comment: The URL for altLabels is now: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/12.4/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html#altlabels

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.pi_flexform.news_pi1.sDEF.settings\.orderBy.altLabels.archive = LLL:EXT:my_theme/pathto.xlf:archive
```

It's important to escape the dot before the fieldname!

- Documentation: [Page TSconfig altLabels](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/12.4/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html#altlabels)

Answer (score 0):

I never tried to use pageTS to localize (only template TS), so I don't know if it is actually possible. I would however suggest localizing the label using the locallang files, in this case creating locallang_db.xlf in appropriate path in `typo3conf/l10n/` with localization for `tx_news_domain_model_news.archive` label.

More info here: https://wiki.typo3.org/Translations#Translation_internals.2C_how_does_it_work.3F

Comment: Imo this is not yet possible this ways as I add the fields with a itemsprocfunc. Open an issue and I can try to fix it. Or you try to add new fields completely by tsconfig (don't know if actually possible)